# Unknown controller type: 'robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController'

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to get the `robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController` working as per [the standard turtorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController). However, when I try to run my RViz, the MoveIt! controller manager claims it cannot find such a controller:

```
[ INFO] [1411628617.460494704]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_controller
[ERROR] [1411628617.460587145]: Unknown controller type: 'robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController'
```

What can be done about this?

Here is my `controllers.yaml` file. Note the `FollowJointTrajectory` controller works fine. Some of the parameters are out of tune but it doesn't make much sense to alter them yet until the actual controller plugin is working.

```
controller_list:
 - name: arm_controller
   action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
   type: FollowJointTrajectory
   default: true
   joints:
     - waist
     - shoulder
     - elbow
     
 - name: r_arm_controller
   action_ns: joint_trajectory_action_controller
   type: "robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController"
   joints:
     - waist
     - shoulder
     - elbow
   gains:
     waist: {p: 1000.0, d: 6.0, i: 600.0, i_clamp: 4.0}
     shoulder: {p: 700.0, d: 4.0, i: 450, i_clamp: 4.0}
     elbow: {p: 300.0, d: 6.0, i: 300, i_clamp: 2.0}
   joint_trajectory_action_node:
     joints:
       - waist
       - shoulder
       - elbow
     constraints:
       goal_time: 10.0
       waist:
         goal: 0.02
       shoulder:
         goal: 0.02
       elbow:
         goal: 0.02
```

How do I get MoveIt! to 'see' the package? I have the package `ros-hydro-robot-mechanism-controllers` installed already, do I need to install something else?

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193444/unknown-controller-type:-%27robot_mechanism_controllers/jointtrajectoryactioncontroller%27/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it should be just "JointTrajectoryActionController", not "robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController".

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-29**:
I tried that, and the same type of error message comes up. Is there any way to list the types of controllers that **are** available?